# How do i display category for each post in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to display category to each of my posts. Through tutorials, I was able to create `MY_Model`, but i am unable to display category on each post.

This is my post model:

```
<?php
class Post_m extends MY_Model
{
    protected $_table_name = 'posts';
    protected $_order_by = 'pubdate desc, id desc';
    protected $_timestamps = TRUE;
    public $rules = array(
        'pubdate' => array(
            'field' => 'pubdate',
            'label' => 'Publication date',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|exact_length[10]'
        ),
        'title' => array(
            'field' => 'title',
            'label' => 'Title',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[100]'
        ),
        'slug' => array(
            'field' => 'slug',
            'label' => 'Slug',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[100]|url_title'
        ),
        'body' => array(
            'field' => 'body',
            'label' => 'Body',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
        )
    );

    public function get_new ()
    {
        $post = new stdClass();
        $post->title = '';
        $post->slug = '';
        $post->body = '';
        $post->name = '';
        $post->post_image = '';
        $post->pubdate = date('Y-m-d');
        return $post;
    }

    public function set_published(){
        $this->db->where('pubdate <=', date('Y-m-d'));
    }

    public function get_recent($limit = 3){

        // Fetch a limited number of recent articles
        $limit = (int) $limit;
        $this->set_published();
        $this->db->limit($limit);
        return parent::get();
    }

    public function get_categories()
    {
        $this->db->order_by('name');
        $query = $this->db->get('categories');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

}
?>
```

Now I want to display the category by name. This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Posts</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php if(count($posts)): foreach ($posts as $key => $post)  if ($key >= 1) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo anchor('admin/posts/edit/' . $post->id, $post->title); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo e(limit_to_numwords(strip_tags($post->body), 10)); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $post->category_id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $post->pubdate; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo btn_edit('admin/posts/edit/' . $post->id); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo btn_delete('admin/posts/delete/' . $post->id); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="center" colspan="3">We could not find any articles.</td>
        </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

If you notice, I added `$post->category_id`, but it only displays INT and not the name of the category.

Please, help!!

Comment: an id is usually `int`, am I missing something? share your db table with example entry as picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted your controller, so I am not exactly sure how you are using your current model, but if you also want to display the name of the category that each post is in, you need to use a join, like this:

```
public function get_posts() {

    $this->db->select('
      categories.id AS category_id,
      categories.name,
      posts.id,
      posts.title,
      posts.body,
      posts.pubdate
    ');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $this->db->join('categories', 'posts.category_id = categories.id');
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();

}
```

What this does is, it gets all of the rows from the posts table, and for each post row it also gets the corresponding category information (including the name) from the categories table. It can find the correct category information using the category's id, which is in each post row. It then returns the information from both tables.

Comment: i tried it and it getting the id of the categories alone, i cant edit a post, cus its referencing the categories' id

Comment: I've edited my original answer, you should now have both a `category_id` and an `id` (of the post) in the result set.